# todo delete/put request not working when create new task

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js, axios, mongodb-query

I'm learning back end development and need some help in mongodb, axios

my project is a simple todo app which stores the created tasks in a mongoDB database.

link of repository is [here](https://github.com/HanyTaha61/MEVN-stack-project)

My problem is when I create a task, I can't mark it as done or delete it until I refresh the page.

I checked the back end server errors and found the attached highlighted error
[image]

I also checked the front end server and found axios error as attached highlighted
[image]

By investigation, I realized that ObjectId expects to receive a hex string or integer as argument, but somehow it receives something else as indicated in the error log from axios (undefined) instead of the task id.

How can I solve that problem?

Comment: You would need to post the code where you make the axios request. I suspect the `undefined` should be the `_id` property value of the mongodb document which will typically be a 24 character hex string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you create the task, you add it to the `todos` array, so it lacks `_id`, which is undefined when passed to the server, giving the error:

```
    await axios.post('http://localhost:5200/', {
        title: this.title,
        duration: this.duration,
        priority: this.priority,
        description: this.description,
        status: this.task_done
    })
        .then(
            this.todos.push({
                title: this.title,
                duration: this.duration,
                priority: this.priority,
                description: this.description,
                status: this.task_done
            })
        )
```

https://github.com/HanyTaha61/MEVN-stack-project/blob/master/src/components/todo-form.vue#L118

The server returns newly created todo id, so add it when pushing to the todos list.

Try changing the above to this:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:5200/', {
        title: this.title,
        duration: this.duration,
        priority: this.priority,
        description: this.description,
        status: this.task_done
    })
    .then(res => {
        this.todos.push({
            _id: res.insertedId,
            title: this.title,
            duration: this.duration,
            priority: this.priority,
            description: this.description,
            status: this.task_done
        });
    })
```

Also, `await` is not needed, because you use `.then`, so you can change that throughout

Comment: Good point. I didn't even notice that I don't use the id returning from the server. 
but when I try to push the newTodo to the todos array, I got another error 
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
    at todo-form.vue:20:83`

there should be another way to return the task id only and include it to the array
I noticed that I can get the id from response

`
{acknowledged: true, insertedId: "65ac4d86e6efe71c1460fc46"}
`

Comment: ah, right, it doesn't return the whole todo object, so just push the task as before, but add the returned _id as well, try the updated code. you could add the id to the todo object like this on the server as well so my first suggestion should work: https://github.com/HanyTaha61/MEVN-stack-project/blob/master/server.js#L100

Comment: Thanks, I retrieved the id successfully from the backend 
But that resulted in another error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase') at todo-form.vue:20:83`

[this is the line contains the error](https://github.com/HanyTaha61/MEVN-stack-project/blob/master/src/components/todo-form.vue#L19)

Comment: is the priority property set? try changing that line to `todo.priority?.toLowerCase()` to make it optional

Comment: this messed out the code and open another bunch of errors
I guess the problem is that `todos` in line 19 is not read as iteratable.
I saw that in a similar case

Comment: maybe because I `get` the data in the `mounted` life cycle hook

Comment: try changing the _id property line to this: `_id: res.data.insertedId,`, but it could be something else...

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution.
After adding a todo task, the form is being reset by the code

```
this.$refs.form.reset()
```

All what should be done is use it inside a `.then` function

```
.then(() => {
                this.$refs.form.reset()
            })
```